# How to call firebase callable functions from Next.Js app? getting "Firebaseerror: not-found"

Tags: javascript, firebase, next.js, google-cloud-functions

I am building a Next.Js app. I want to call a simple "Https Callable function" provided by the firebase.

Function is:

```
exports.addData = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
console.log(data)
const userId = context.auth.uid;
const respnseData = { 
      message: data,
      userId: userId
   }
 return respnseData;
});
```

I am trying to call it from /api/index.js file in Next.Js project

```
import { httpsCallable } from "firebase/functions";
import { functions } from "../../utils/firebaseConfig";

export default async function handler(req, res) {
const addData = httpsCallable(functions, "addData");
const data = {
     param1: "value1",
     param2: "value2",
  };
const result = await addData(JSON.stringify(data))
console.log("result", result) 
}
```

But I am getting the following error every time:

[image]

Network Tab looks like this -

[image]

Can somebody please help me out what exactly the problem is?

The Error message says:

> Firebaseerror: not-found

I am trying to call a callable firebase function from "Firebase functions emulators".

Comment: Hi I have recreated the issue with typescript next js project and I am able to get the console.log of result at `http://localhost:3000/api` on server terminal here's the [**snippet**](https://codefile.io/f/FB0iaAA0WZpXPHZCYmWZ) for my recreation

Comment: @RohitKharche have you tried without login ? I mean without implementing SignWithEmailAndPassword ? Also, did you get the result after deploying functions to the firebase or just on emulators ?

Comment: Yes I am able to console.log the result as ```result {   data: { message: { param1: 'value1', param2: 'value2' }, userId: null } } ```.  I have also updated the snippet with firebase functions code in the above snippet I have shared .